# How to disregard part of an RDD string for operations

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a file and each line is structured as:

```
500, 1733345329, A, ugly, 500, 1230, 99
2, 1171253353, picB, wow, 1660, 20, 213
...
```

My goal is to manipulate the last 3 digits (500, 1230, 99) of each line and attach is to the first int as a key. Is there a way to use map in this case where I can extract parts of a string such as these and use them in operations such as summing them?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am trying to do this in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the text file, split the lines by comma, and map to a tuple with the first integer as the key and an array of the last three integers as the value.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("filepath.txt")

val rdd2 = rdd.map(_.split(", ")).map(r => (r(0).toInt, Array(r(4), r(5), r(6)).map(_.toInt)))
// rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Int])]

rdd2.collect
// Array[(Int, Array[Int])] = Array((500,Array(500, 1230, 99)), (2,Array(1660, 20, 213)))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I forgot to mention I was doing this in Java. I understand the process you've put but where I am falling apart is not know how to do this logic syntactically within Java.